# Extract property value in filename?

Tags: string, bash

I have many file paths of the form:

```
dir1/someotherdir/name_q=3_a=2.34_p=1.2.ext
```

I am running a bash script to do some processing on these files, and I need to extract the value of `p` (in this case 1.2; in general it is a floating number) from each of these paths. Basically I am running a `for` loop over all the file paths, and for each path, I need to extract the value of `p`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) is a useful tool for this kind of operation:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ IMPORTANT: Not /bin/sh

f=dir1/someotherdir/name_q=3_a=2.34_p=1.2.ext

if [[ $f = *_p=* ]]; then  # Check for substring in filename
  val=${f##*_p=}           # Trim everything before the last "_p="
  val=${val%%_*}           # Trim everything after first subsequent _
  val=${val%.ext}          # Trim extension, should it exist.
  echo "Extracted $val from filename $f"
fi
```

---

Alternately, you could also use shell-native regex support:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ again, NOT /bin/sh

f=dir1/someotherdir/name_q=3_a=2.34_p=1.2.ext

# assigning regex to a variable avoids surprising behavior with some older bash releases
p_re='_p=([[:digit:].]+)(_|[.]ext$)'

if [[ $f =~ $p_re ]]; then             # evaluate regex
  echo "Extracted ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  # extract groups from BASH_REMATCH array
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, another approach is to use `eval`.  There can be security dangers here, you have to make your own mind-up if these are justified.

I am using `IFS` for the split - not everyone's favourite, but it is another way to do it.  The `eval` will execute each assignment as it finds it, in this case dynamically creating variables `q`, `a`, and `p`.

```
fname='dir1/someotherdir/name_q=3_a=2.34_p=1.2.ext'

OldIFS="$IFS"

IFS='_'
for val in $fname
do
    if [[ $val == *=* ]]
    then
        val=${val%.ext}
        eval "$val"
    fi
done
IFS="$OldIFS"
echo "$q"
echo "$a"
echo "$p"
```

Comment: What value does `eval` add to this code? What can you do with it that you couldn't do equally well without it?

Comment: (Other thon the obvious, that is, execution of code embedded in a filename -- but I'd call honoring `name_evil=$(rm -rf ~)` a bug rather than a feature).